# decoding json problem, returns null value

Tags: php, json

my solution was :

```
function format_json($str)
  {
    ...
    $str = preg_replace('/([a-z]+):/i', '"$1":', $str);
    $wtr = array('""',',",');
    $rpw = array('"',',');
    return str_replace($wtr, $rpw, $str);
  }
```

Comment: Keys and strings must be in double quotes. Where do you get the JSON from?

Comment: Note: This is valid JavaScript but not valid JSON. Valid JavaScript is not automatically valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like stated in previous answers, you need to add double-quote to strings. A really fast and quick way to check json string is to use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Here's the output you will get from JSONLint:

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    m: [        {     
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

So you need to change all parts that don't have double quotes. For example:

```
{m: [ ...
```

Will become:

```
{"m": [ ...
```

**Edit after comment:** It seems that the double quotes inside strings are not escaped properly. For example:

```
{"m" : [ { "g": [ "32", "Brezilya-"Serie" A", "83", ...
Here -----------------------------^ and ^
```

Should be:

```
{"m" : [ { "g": [ "32", "Brezilya-\"Serie\" A", "83", ...
```

Comment: No worries. I hope it works out for you. Haha, just noticed what I wrote "fast and quick". It's like saying "big and large" :P

Comment: :D, all strings are now in double quotes but now the JSONLint says " invalid array length " ....

Comment: yes i see, but the probles it that the function which adds keys inside double quotes ( ex : m to " m " ) some times does things like  "Brezilya-"Serie" A".. i will try to fix it

Answer (score 2):

JSON only supports double-quoted strings, and all of the property names must be quoted.

Comment: just tried... don't work , the JSONLint says : " invalid array length "

Comment: Can you update your question with the data after the fixes you made?

Comment: ok i updated my question, now you can see the data after some changes

Comment: oh... the function to place keys in double quotes did some wrong things... i will try to fix it..

Comment: It looks like you surrounded a lot words with double quotes, so now some strings aren't valid. See `"Brezilya-"Serie" A"` for example: that isn't a valid string.

Comment: @John let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1870/discussion-between-clueless-and-john)

Answer (score 2):

Try to run your JSON through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). To begin with, property names must be enclosed in double quotes. Then, strings must also be enclosed in double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
{
    "m": [
        {
            "g": [
                32,
                "Brezilya-SerieA",
                .
                .
                .
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse this string with class from here http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=198

require_once 'JSON.php';
$json = new Services_JSON();
$data  =  $json->decode($yourstring);

Answer (score 1):

IN your JSON you should use " " instead of  ' '  and that will get solved.

its a convention in JSON that the double qoutes will be used to define object names or objects .. try using the way u write a string in C++ for defining your json .

Comment: sorry, but have you read all question? I said i tried to replace single quotes '' with double quotes " " but it also don't work...

Comment: checking again for fixin it now and telling u whats wrong gimme 1 min

Comment: you need to quote the m aswell i mean it should look like {"m":[{"g" instead of {m:[{g did u tried properly qouting all the properties i think thats where its bugging  ?

Comment: I will write a little function now to put all strings in quotes... thanks

Comment: No problem :) :) you should rather parse json on client side using JSON.stringify( object ) method in JavaSCRIPT  or json_encode( object ) if thats PHP

Comment: i tried but it dont work, now it looks like ' {"m":[{"g" ' but now the error is " invalid array length "... what is that?